# Regex to search asset tags on AutoCAD drawings

Tags: python, regex, autocad

I have refrained from posting a question here because I wanted to do my bit to find myself a solution to this issue. But unfortunately, after entire nights of searching and reading different Regex articles and docs I couldn't find an answer.

I have written a script that spills out the comment from PDF that have been converted from AutoCAD. Problem is, which drawing has a different pattern of the asset tag information.

Our convention is `99XX9999` (two-numbers, two-letters, four-numbers).

Some drawings preserve that pattern, others don't. We can find things like `99XX(space)9999` OR `99(space)XX(space)9999`, etc.

That part of the problem I resolved it, but there's another variant that I can't wrap my head around as per below:

'''

> {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '0811', '/F': 64, '/NM':
> 'b4499c47-d2d2-4c03-b13c-ec3b7b332ec3', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0),
> '/Rect': [714, 304, 698, 314], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD
> SHX
> Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '29', '/F': 64, '/NM':
> 'b518c663-42eb-4861-a717-a00118d61fd2', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0),
> '/Rect': [206, 369, 195, 378], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD
> SHX
> Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': 'HV', '/F': 64, '/NM':
> '1db0a6b1-6aee-4a2d-bacf-2a996680cdcb', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0),
> '/Rect': [212, 369, 201, 378], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD
> SHX
> Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '0832', '/F': 64, '/NM':
> '0250033f-5bc0-4d46-879a-a1ae0147352d', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0),
> '/Rect': [212, 365, 195, 374], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD
> SHX
> Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '29', '/F': 64, '/NM':
> '7b372206-1b18-4c9f-813d-4d73ca52be40', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0),
> '/Rect': [140, 392, 129, 401], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD
> SHX
> Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': 'HV', '/F': 64, '/NM':
> 'bdc97ccd-ee7c-406a-a06c-1649a5f5f712', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0),
> '/Rect': [146, 392, 135, 401], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD
> SHX
> Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '0824', '/F': 64, '/NM':
> '9f434537-57a3-4c40-bb8b-a0df6ea087aa', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0),
> '/Rect': [146, 388, 129, 397], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD
> SHX
> Text'}--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '%%C25', '/F': 64, '/NM': 'a2ace5cb-21be-4df7-b541-ce87a8ee81bc', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [145, 379, 132, 388], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': 'APOUTO RD', '/F': 64, '/NM': '948a363f-989d-4d00-afa1-a8bc45ad9729', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [1162, 355, 1136, 364], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': 'HORTICULTURAL WATER', '/F': 64, '/NM': '5a6cedb6-cdf0-4784-817f-c17f1de58f5a', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [1171, 350, 1126, 358], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '%%C101', '/F': 64, '/NM': '2ee5947a-9062-415f-a242-f4b7b2a6441c', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [767, 428, 758, 443], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'''

We can see '/Contents': '29'...then '/Contents': 'HV'...then '/Contents': '0832'...

I have tried multiple variations of this approach `(?<='/Contents':\s')([0-9]{2})(?=')` on regex101.com to no avail. I could only capture the first two digits.

In my logic, I should find a way to have multiple 'lookaround' but couldn't achieve that.

Eventually, the regex code should the above plus the ones I already go it `([A-Z]?[0-9]{2,3}\s?[A-Z]{2,3}\s?[0-9]{3,4})`.

The line break happens after the three parts of the pattern happen, according to the regex101.com site (see picture).

Just to be clear, I am talking about 100s of drawings with 100s of lines like that each .

Please, any contribution is appreciated. If not regex itself, at least a direction I should take would be nice.

Regards, [image]

Comment: that's just a dictionary. why don't you just read it?

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Although, I am not quite sure how to achieve that, I will do some more digging into it. Regards,

Comment: question is not clear.  I have no idea what you're asking.  you want to match the /Contents value? https://regex101.com/r/88MhFj/1/

Comment: Hi Scott, sorry for the confusion as English is my second language. 
I want to match this pattern 99XX9999 (two-numbers, two-letters, four-numbers). The problem is that this pattern is scattered all over the text above. I don't want to match '/Contents' but what I want is right after that, in three installments, each after their own '/Contents' statement: 29  HV  0832 , for instance. I want them together as 29HV0832. Does that make sense?

Comment: And thanks for your previous answer, Scott. The only issues is that it captures other things as well I am not interested in. Pardon me for not having added the remained sample data above. I was trying to be concise. I have updated the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one**.

```
s="{'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '0811', '/F': 64, '/NM': 'b4499c47-d2d2-4c03-b13c-ec3b7b332ec3', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [714, 304, 698, 314], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '29', '/F': 64, '/NM': 'b518c663-42eb-4861-a717-a00118d61fd2', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [206, 369, 195, 378], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': 'HV', '/F': 64, '/NM': '1db0a6b1-6aee-4a2d-bacf-2a996680cdcb', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [212, 369, 201, 378], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '0832', '/F': 64, '/NM': '0250033f-5bc0-4d46-879a-a1ae0147352d', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [212, 365, 195, 374], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '29', '/F': 64, '/NM': '7b372206-1b18-4c9f-813d-4d73ca52be40', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [140, 392, 129, 401], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': 'HV', '/F': 64, '/NM': 'bdc97ccd-ee7c-406a-a06c-1649a5f5f712', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [146, 392, 135, 401], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '0824', '/F': 64, '/NM': '9f434537-57a3-4c40-bb8b-a0df6ea087aa', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [146, 388, 129, 397], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '%%C25', '/F': 64, '/NM': 'a2ace5cb-21be-4df7-b541-ce87a8ee81bc', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [145, 379, 132, 388], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': 'APOUTO RD', '/F': 64, '/NM': '948a363f-989d-4d00-afa1-a8bc45ad9729', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [1162, 355, 1136, 364], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': 'HORTICULTURAL WATER', '/F': 64, '/NM': '5a6cedb6-cdf0-4784-817f-c17f1de58f5a', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [1171, 350, 1126, 358], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- {'/Border': [0, 0, 0], '/Contents': '%%C101', '/F': 64, '/NM': '2ee5947a-9062-415f-a242-f4b7b2a6441c', '/P': IndirectObject(52, 0), '/Rect': [767, 428, 758, 443], '/Subtype': '/Square', '/T': 'AutoCAD SHX Text'}--------------------------------------------------------------------------------}"


A=B=C=''
for i in s.split("/Contents': '"):
  e=i[ 0 : i.index(",")-1]
  if e.isdigit() and len(e) == 2 :
      A=e
  if e.isalpha() and len(e) == 2 :   
      B=e
  if e.isdigit() and len(e) == 4 :
      C=e
      print(A+B+C)
      A=B=C=''
```

[**Output**]:

```
0811
29HV0832
29HV0824
```

Comment: That works brilliantly, mate. Thank you so much for your assistance on this.
As a 'noobie', I thought I could do this with regex alone. My mistake #1. Gotta involve some coding to achieve that. 
I believe I now have what it takes to concatenate the output into the 99XX9999 format now.

Best regards to all. Close this ticket ;-P

Comment: @WashingtonAlmeida. Now the code is Updated to concatenate the output into 99XX9999 form.

Comment: I apologize, @WiktorStribi*ew, that was an attempt at being funny that failed. Best wishes. Thanks again, @AziMex! I have now marked as resolved.